# setTimeout with a stack of function calls

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have an ajax funtion that returns a list of items. I then fetch some pricing info on those items. The pricing info comes from an outside resource and is kinda slow, so I always load the items make appropriate DOM changes, then fetch the prices. The issue is that I need a delay between price calls. What I want is as follows:

```
loadPricesDelayed
 delay 5sec
loadPricesDelayed
 delay 5sec
loadPricesDelayed
 delay 5sec
loadPricesDelayed
```

What I have currently is this:

```
        $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
            ***
            loadPrices(obj.prod, obj.mfg);
            ***
         } 

        function loadPrices(cardName, setName) {
            if (outstandingPricesToFetch == 1)
                setTimeout(function () { loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg) }, 5000);
            else {
                outstandingPricesToFetch = 1;
                loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg);             
            }              
        }

        var outstandingPricesToFetch;

        function loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg) {
             ****
        }
```

(outstandingPricesToFetch gets reset pre $.each to prevent a delay on the first fetch)

This code results in the following

```
loadPricesDelayed
 delay 5sec
loadPricesDelayed
loadPricesDelayed
loadPricesDelayed
```

How would I break the delay up as intended?

Comment: Do you specifically **need** a delay of 5 seconds between the various calls, or is this just being done so that there is enough time for the data to process? Because if you're just trying to ensure the data comes back **after** the function, you would benefit from a **callback** :)

Comment: Or use a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) chain. jQuery has it builtin or you could use a separate library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Specifically creating a delay because of requirements from the outside resource. We have had large sample sets trigger DDOS protection from their CDN

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code, It is multiplying the delay time to get desired result.

```
$.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
            ***
            loadPrices(obj.prod, obj.mfg,i);//**change**
            ***
         } 

        function loadPrices(cardName, setName,i) {//**change**
            if (outstandingPricesToFetch == 1)
                setTimeout(function () { loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg) }, 5000*i);//change
            else {
                outstandingPricesToFetch = 1;
                loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg);             
            }              
        }

        var outstandingPricesToFetch;

        function loadPricesDelayed(prod, mfg) {
             ****
        }
```

**Above code will fire loadPricesDelayed at 0,5,10,15,20 second.**

Comment: Sorry amit but I would advise not to use setTimeout for control flow. Unless this is a pet project, use callbacks, promises, rxjs or async/await.

Comment: I agree  with what you said, But still thought  to atleast provide the solution to divide delay equally between function call, But again i totally agree with what you said as we cannot guarantee that load... will give response in 5 sec